# Caller ID on Attended Transfer

Tags: asterisk

Actual Caller ID on Attended transfer is not working.

I have configured the ami atxfer and it does attended transfer the calls. 
    I also saved the actual Caller id in variable and set the variable before 
    attended transfer.
    but when Agent A attended transfer the call to Agent B. 
    The Caller id shows as asterisk @ asterisk on Agent B phone. 
    Agent B sometime receives actual Caller ID.
    but mostly Agent B receives asterisk @ asterisk.

```
[bellcab]    
exten => 0,1,Answer()
exten => 0,n,Set(__cid=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 0,n,Set(__uniqueid=${CHANNEL(uniqueid)})
exten => 0,n(bellreturncall),Queue(bellcab,t,,,,/scripts/bell_cab/call_log.php,,,,${QUEUEPOSITION})
exten => 0,n,Hangup()

[bellcab-atxfer-call]
exten => _XXXX,1,SIPAddHeader(X-Call-Uniqueid:${uniqueid})
exten => _XXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${cid})
exten => _XXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,t)
exten => _XXXX,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Here is CLI with Caller ID asterisk @ asterisk
https://pastebin.com/PKer0K07

Here is CLI with Actual Caller ID
https://pastebin.com/XQKC7uLm

Answer (score 0):

You have play with sendrpid/trustrpid params.

Also for send cid need add **o** to dialler flags

```
exten => _XXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,ot)
```

Comment: I have 
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=pai
and i also tried o and o(${cid}) option in dial application. but same result.
please see following CLIs
with o option https://pastebin.com/rQNRHDsG
with o(${cid}) https://pastebin.com/ru2MRCqR

Thanks.

Comment: just o, without anything.

Comment: I tried just o but it did not work., please see the CLI https://pastebin.com/rQNRHDsG